# yodlee - account type (Transactions will be listed to what type of bank account)

Tags: transactions, yodlee

I am developing one website with yodlee integration.

For testing, i gave my saving account type net banking details.

I got this in my get transaction list webservice call but only account info is displaying without any info on transactions.

But with that testing account, i have done so much of transactions but nothing get from yodlee.

Pls guide me that where i have done mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain which API you are using? If you are not using [**executeUserSearchRequest**](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest) then please use this to get transactions.